# Using bootstrapValidator in Twitter Bootstrap Wizard

Tags: jqbootstrapvalidation, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

how can validate a Twitter Bootstrap Wizard form  on onNext event with bootstrapValidator?

Answer (score -1):

You can the `index` value returned by the callback function to determine the current step and validate it. If one or more of the required fields are found invalid, you can return `false` to the `onNext` event. This will prevent the wizard from advancing to the next step.

I have written a complete tutorial on [Creating Bootstrap form wizard with Javascript Validation](http://codezag.com/bootstrap-form-wizard-with-validation/) on my blog.

I hope it helps.